# Can I use data from the Amazon API in my App?

Tags: api, web-api

I'm having a hard time finding information on this, but using the Amazon API (such as the [ItemSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) api) provides you with data on Amazon products. In my case I am interested in books.

The Amazon API generates links to pictures of the books and details on the books.

I want to use this in my smartphone app, but Google appears to want proof that I am allowed to display that information in my app. They are saying that the book information and particularly book covers, could be copyrighted and I need to show proof I can use those in my app.

The Amazon API is free and they give you a key and what not for you to use.

**Could anyone who knows something about this either enlighten me or better yet, provide a link to some sort of FAQs or documentation that tells me outright whether I can or cannot use data from the Amazon API in my web-app or smartphone app or whatever app?**

I can't for the life of me find what I am looking for and Amazon is so big.

Cheers!

Comment: Irony: multiple publishers have accused Google of copyright infringement with their [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) project.

Answer (score 1):

INAL, but it was quite easy to find [the relevant license agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html), where it says:

> #### 2. Enrollment
>
> To begin the enrollment process, you must submit a complete and accurate enrollment form. In your enrollment form, you must describe the application you intend to develop and use with the Product Advertising API or on which you intend to display Product Advertising Content. We will evaluate your enrollment form and notify you of its acceptance or rejection. We may reject your enrollment form if we determine that your application is unsuitable. Unsuitable applications include those that:

In other words, it seems like you need to explicitly request the permission from Amazon to use that data in your application. If Amazon accepts your enrollment form and grants you a permission, you can display it to Google as the proof they require. If Amazon rejects your request you are not allowed to use their data in your application anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I shall investigate further. What is the link to where you got that information? And any clue where I can actually find this enrollment form (if you happen to have crossed paths with it?)

Comment: I already put a link in the answer - it's the orange-colored text that says "_the relevant license agreement_"

Comment: ah there it is. The color of this site makes it hard to see... Thanks. Any idea about where the actual form is though? Can't seem to find it on google.

Comment: I googled around a bit and someone posted an official answer from Amazon: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=143432#143432